# How to breaks highcharts x-Axis category

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created one sample dateTime `Highchart` as per shown in Image.But I want to break x-axis from value "03/24/2014" to value "12/15/2014".Is this possible to break it?? Highchart provides breaks functionality for numbers category , you can refer it from [Here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.breaks) . So I need help and thanks in advance.Below is code snippet

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart:{type:'scatter'},
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval:24 * 3600 * 1000*7 ,


        type: 'datetime',
        labels:
        {

            rotation: -90,
            formatter:
           function () {
               return Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d/%Y', this.value)
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip:{ hideDelay: 100, headerFormat: '<b>{point.x:%m/%d/%Y} - {point.key}</b><br/>', pointFormat: '{series.name}:{point.y}'},
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000*7 
    },{
        data: [9.9, 7.5, 16.4, 12.2, 44.0, 16.0, 35.6, 18.5, 16.4, 14.1, 9.6, 4.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000*7 
    }]
});
```

[image: Highchart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exactly doesn't work for you? Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4188/

```
        breaks: [{
            from: Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1) + 12 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7, //12 points
            to: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1),
            breakSize: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7
        }],
```

Comment: Fus : your solution is worked perfectly as per asked question.But now problem is that I have two or more series with different dates and I have to plot this date between week range.Lets say if one of series data has date "01/01/2013" and another has "11/12/2015".If I use week timeInterval then It make chart very long contain 2 years week interval.so I need to plot that week interval which contain series date.Is there any way to do it? I am very thankful to you

Comment: Hm.. change week interval? To something that suits you? I'm not sure where is the problem. Do you have live demo?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4190/   .Here is woking demo example and related comment is also there in code snippet , Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you want to use `ordinal` axis (available only in the Highstock lib): http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4191/ - note: it requires is also change to line series, instead of scatter. Otherwise, you need to calculate each break before creating chart.

Comment: Pawel Fus  Hi, can you please guide me for this link , if possible ??http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4196/  thanks in advance

Comment: In such case, maybe it's better to use [grouped-categories](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin?